# Subtractive cancellation errors in the lab

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I am quite familiar with the problem associated with loss of significance in numerical analysis. This problem seems to be an even bigger problem in the science lab, where subtracting one physical measurement from another produces potentially tremendous error because the uncertanties in the measurement don't subtract, but add.

Question: Is there a special name for this type of error associated with subtraction when applied to the physical measurement? Does anyone know any resources that specifically target this problem?

Comment: I have only encountered "cancellation". Why do you think there is a special name for it?

Comment: Because the error can be so enormous. It has a special name in numerical analysis (subtractive cancellation, catastrophic cancellation, loss of signficance) so I figured that there would be a term for it in physics.

Comment: I would argue that that kind of mistake is much less common in a laboratory setting, mainly because it is much more obvious when you are about to make it.  Suppose that I need to know the width of a hair. I might think to drive my car from Cleveland OH to one edge of the hair, then drive from Cleveland to the other edge of the hair, and take the difference between the two odometer readings. Sounds silly, but a novice programmer, unfamiliar with the nature of floating point arithmetic, and unable to visualize what the numbers mean, actually _could_ make a mistake of that magnitude.

Comment: The mistake doesn't just arise when finding the changes in physical properties, it also appears in vector summation when two vectors are pointing in the same direction. It showed up in our collision theory class, where some students' loss-in-momentum calculations were larger than others'. It was purely from the order in which they summed numbers.

Comment: It is important to differentiate between absolute and relative errors. Subtraction does not produce catastrophic errors but cancellation can produce singular behaviour in terms of relative errors.

Comment: "Loss of significance" is just as good a term in physics as it is in numeric analysis. And of course, every even passably capable experimenter is all too familiar with it and has tricks for building experiments in which it does *less* damage. But it's just this thing that you have to work around.

Comment: Agreed. Keep in mind that my students are not passably capable experimenters. I'm trying to get them there. :)